# C++ console application stops working and does not fulfill its task after returning to normal

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a question on Project Euler but my code has an interesting problem. It freezes at some point, comes back and ends without completing the task. I know the program is power hungry(for a few reasons, I have optimization ideas...) but I have worked with heavier programs which did work. So there probably is something worse than poor optimization going on here. Code Blocks does not show any errors while building by the way so ı dont think it is about basic syntax.
Here is the problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=8
And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> numbers;
    int current=1;
    int a;
    string series = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    boost::split(numbers,series,boost::is_any_of(""));
    int larf=current;
    for(int a=0;a<=987;a++){
        for (int i=0+a;i<=12+a;i++){
            current = current*atoi(numbers[i].c_str());
        }
        if (current > larf){
            larf = current;
        }
        current=1;
    }
    cout << "The greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number is:"<< larf;
    cin >> a; //to make the program pause
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for taking your time and reading through this.The large number stored as a string is 1000-digits long by the way. Sorry for the long question.

Edit: the compiler now gives 2 errors while building:

> ld.exe:       cannot open output file bin\Debug\Largest product in a series.exe
>                Permission denied
>                error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   === Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===

Comment: Sleep(50) at outer for loop may help.

Comment: I would use some cout statements inside the for loop to see how far it gets before having issues. I don't see any obvious things that should cause a problem

Comment: It looks like You haven't killed the program before compiling it again. A running program cannot be overridden with a new one, if it is running.

Comment: Disable your installed anti-malware product and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split string is not working the way you think it is. Your program is failing due to out of range access(es).

Frankly, you are adding steps that are unnecessary. As you are only working with individual digits, you can get a digit value without the intermediaries:

```
int digit_value = series[n] - '0';
```

This works over any character set that does not violate C & C++ language specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This information might prove useful in days to come. Thought the "cannot open output file" still exists. Do you have any suggestions? I will let you know if I solve this.

Comment: @user, the cannot open output file has nothing to do with C++. Just make sure that your program is not running. Use the Program Manager search for it and kill it. If the software is running, Windows locks the file in Read Only mode. Frankly, you should switch to Linux, much better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you split your input into strings?  That's totally unnecessary and inefficient.  A string is but an array of chars, converting an ASCII char to a number takes 1 subtraction.

```
#include <iostream>

const char* DATA = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

int main()
{
    const char* p = DATA;
    const char* q = p;
    int i = 0;

    // check input
    for (i = 0; i < 13; ++i, ++q) 
        if (*q <= '0' || '9' <= *q)
            break;

    if (i < 13)
    {
        std::cout << "error: input too short\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // compute first factor
    int result = *p - '0';
    for (const char* pp = p + 1; pp < q; ++pp)
        result *= (*pp - '0');

    while ('0' <= *q && *q <= '9')
    {
        ++p;
        ++q;

        int factor = *p - '0';
        for (const char* pp = p + 1; pp < q; ++pp)
            factor *= (*pp - '0');

        if (factor > result)
            result = factor;
    }

    std::cout << "result: " << result << '\n';    

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made another file. It seems I somehow do not have permission to delete or alter a file in the original project... in administrator windows account... life is strange indeed.

Thank you all for answering. I sure learned things thjat might help me better optimize my code in the future.